# Division of array items with an integer?

Tags: c++

I am trying to divide the items of an array with "1000", and I think my syntax is wrong, kindly help!

data[99] contains the values from 1-100 while two[99] is empty.

```
float two[99];
for(int x=0; x<100; x++)
{
  two[x]=data[x]/1000;
}
```

Comment: And what's the problem?

Comment: The code has undefined behaviour as array indexes are zero based (`N` to `N - 1` where `N` is the number of elements in the array) and `two[99]` is one too many.

Comment: There is a compiler to check your syntax errors.

Comment: You're indexing out of bounds. The array `two` contain 99 entries, indexed from `0` to `98`.

Comment: data is int basically, but even when i change it to float, it dsnt work.

Comment: @MomoPomo: We need more code...

Comment: @MomoPomo: If `data` is an `int`, then you get integer division, which would set all entries to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a zero-based indexes array so you need:

```
float two[100];
for(int x=0; x<100; x++)
{
   two[x]=(float)data[x]/(float)1000;
}
```

I added the (float) conversion to make sure you get the expected values, since we don't know the type of data[…].

Comment: He's searching for the value of `two[99]` so you must define `float two[100];`

Comment: data[99] is already been declared as float.
and yes, float two[99] is the size of array

Comment: @MM. Right. +1. I modified the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Define `two` like this:

```
float two[100]; // 99 + 1
```

Arrays start from `0` in C/C++, so `two[99]` refers to 100th item of `two`.

Comment: okay, i wrote, 

float two[100];
for(int x=0; x<=100; x++);
{
two[x]=data[x]/1000.0;
}

its aint working now, too

Comment: @MomoPomo: What's the result now?

Comment: ERROR
"invalid types `int[99][float]' for array subscript "

Answer (score 2):

The syntax is okay, the logic is wrong. `float two[99];` has `99` items - `0` through `98` - `two[99]` is illegal.

Comment: float one[99];
    one[k] = data[k] -= mean;

is giving me the correct answers, then why not two[99]?
i hav taken [99] to get 100 empty spaces, starting from 1 and ending at 99... so to store a total of 100 answers.